# Fail to read file in Android Service

Tags: android, media-player, ioexception

I want to play a video a.m4v in live wallpaper by using the APIDemo's MediaPlayer.
I used the following code and works fine in MediaPlayer activity.

```
       AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.a);
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
```

It fails when I put the code in LivWallpaperService.  I think it is due to file permission.

```
04-05 12:32:58.598: D/MediaPlayerDemo(5308): onPrepared called
04-05 12:32:58.598: V/MediaPlayerDemo(5308): startVideoPlayback
04-05 12:32:59.153: D/MediaPlayerDemo(5308): player starting
04-05 12:33:00.004: E/MediaPlayer(5308): error (1, -19)
04-05 12:33:00.004: E/MediaPlayer(5308): Error (1,-19)
```

Therefore I try to copy the file into a temp file, but still getting the error.

```
                InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.a);

            File tempfile = File.createTempFile("mediaplayer", "temp",this.getCacheDir());
            String tempfilepath = tempfile.getAbsolutePath();
             FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(tempfile);
             BufferedOutputStream bis = new BufferedOutputStream(fo);

             int count = 0;
             byte buf[] = new byte[128];
             do {

              int numread = is.read(buf);
              count+=numread;
              if (numread <= 0)
               break;
              bis.write(buf, 0, numread);
             } while (true); 

             Log.d(TAG, "tempfile.length()"+tempfile.length());

             Log.d(TAG, is.toString());


             mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(tempfilepath)


04-05 12:46:36.981: E/MediaPlayerDemo(6000): error: null
04-05 12:46:36.981: E/MediaPlayerDemo(6000): java.lang.IllegalStateException
04-05 12:46:36.981: E/MediaPlayerDemo(6000):    at
android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
```

Anybody knows why I can't read from an AssetFileDescriptor?

and why I can't read a file I created inside the package?

Answer (score 1):

Android `/asset` is only accessible to application itself so you can't. No other application can access resources inside the /asset directory of your application.

So copy it to `internal storage` or `external storage` and use it is good idea.

Just check your file in `/temp` directory has `WORLD_READABLE` permission.

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

Comment: I tried and still got the same error.
it is just "different" between running the code in activity and WallpaperService.